# Library's Activity injection using dagger

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, architecture, dagger-2

I start dagger2 evaluation for dependency injection in an Android application and have some questions regarding my current architecture.

I have several modules in my project:

```
app1/
app2/
libA/
```

This setup allows me to share common pieces (incl. some Activities) between several applications.

Using dagger2 to inject dependency in an application module is ok, I build the component in my app with its modules and from my Activity I retrieve the component from the Application to inject dependencies.

`app1/MyApplication.java`

```
public MyApplication extends Application
{
  private MyComponent mMyComponent;


  @Override
  public void onCreate()
  {
    // bind & inject dependencies
    mMyComponent = DaggerMyComponent.builder()
        .myModule(new MyModule(this))
        .build();
  }

  MyComponent getMyComponent()
  {
    return mMyComponent;
  }
}
```

`app1/MyActivity.java`

```
public MyActivity extends Activity
{

  @Inject
  MyDependency mDependency;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final MyComponent myComponent = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getMyComponent();
    myComponent.inject(this);
  }
}
```

What bothers me is the tight coupling between `MyActivity` and `MyApplication`, or `MyComponent` to process injection.
If I have another activity `MyActivity2` defined in `libA/`, I'm stuck and can't inject dependencies.

I'm not sure how to proceed.
I saw a similar question here: [Multi-layer / libraries architecture with dagger2: designing scopes, components, modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43783527/multi-layer-libraries-architecture-with-dagger2-designing-scopes-components) and an answer refers to a sample application project with this kind of setup except that the library module doesn't inject dependencies in an Activity.

I made an ugly workaround to move forward but it's really not satisfying:

I added an `Injector` interface:

```
public interface Injector
{
  void inject(Object target);
}
```

And then `MyApplication` implements `Injector` allowing me to write something like:

`libA/MyActivity2`

```
public MyActivity2 extends Activity
{

  @Inject
  MyDependency mDependency;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ((Injector) getApplication()).inject(this);
  }
}
```

It cuts the dependency to both `MyApplication` and `MyComponent`.
And then, the ugly part is the inject implementation which tests objects against all supported classes (using `instanceof`) and call the proper `inject(MyActivity2)` method.

```
@Component(modules={MyModule.class})
@Singleton
public abstract class MyComponent
{

  public void inject(Object target)
  {
    // FIXME the ugly part
    if (target instanceof MyApplication)
      inject((MyApplication) target);
    else if (target instanceof MyActivity)
      inject((MyActivity) target);
    else if (target instanceof MyActivity2)
      inject((MyActivity2) target);
  }

  public abstract void inject(MyApplication target);

  public abstract void inject(MyActivity target);

  public abstract void inject(MyActivity2 target);

}
```

Comment: Before you create your own interfaces and abstractions you could have a look at the new android package of Dagger. It is still in beta as of v2.11. It defines an interface for your Android components, and will handle the injection of your app.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak, I saw this thanks to your comment, and the description seems close to my use case. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: After testing, I confirm it works but requires a lot of boilerplate. At least, no more tight coupling. Thanks.